# SWRL rule to compare 2 string datatype property

Tags: swrl

I would like to ask you if we can creat an `SWRL` rule that permit to compare 2 datatype property of type `string` ?
For instance,  if we have have 2 classes : `situation` class that has `has_situation_type` as `datatype` property `(srting)`, and service class that has `has_service_type` as `datatype` property `(string)`.
I want to create a rule as following:

If these two classes have the same `datatype` property `has_services_type = has_situation_type` than situation will trigger service.
I try to exprime this rule in `SWRL` but I don't know if it is possible:

```
service(?service), situation(?situation), has_services_type(?service,?a), has_situation_type(?situation,?b), equal(?a, ?b) -> trigger (?situation, ?service).
```

**NB:** I know that `equal` is used just for numbers and not for string, but I don't know how can I do it for string. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I was wrong, we can do it with **swrlb:equal** as following:

```
service(?service), situation(?situation), has_services_type(?service,?a), has_situation_type(?situation,?b), swrlb:equal(?a, ?b) -> trigger (?situation, ?service)
```

and it works now ^_^